# React splice returns opposite of what I delete?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, slice, splice

I am trying to delete first two, three, four indices of an array. This is my code:

```
 returnFilteredRoles() {
    if (this.props.user.role_id == 1 || this.props.user.role_id == 2) {
      return this.state.data;
    } else if (this.props.user.role_id == 3) {
      return this.state.data.splice(0, 2);
    } else if (this.props.user.role_id == 4) {
      return this.state.data.splice(0, 3);
    } else if (this.props.user.role_id == 5) {
      return this.state.data.splice(0, 4);
    }
  }
```

ex: `data = [1,2,3,4,5]`;
`if role_id == 3`, it should return `[3,4,5]`. instead it returns `[1,2]`. no Idea why.

I tried storing the state into a variable and splicing that variable and returning that. But it gives same result.

Comment: The arguments to slice are the [start and end index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). If start index is 0 you're going to get a section of the array starting at the first item. All of your slices start at zero, so you get a chunk from the beginning of the array.

Comment: I read in a tutorial that first argument is starting index and second is the number of items to delete. thanks for clarification.

Comment: [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) are two different things. _splice_ takes the number of items to delete. _slice_ does not.

Comment: okay, but somehow splice was returning the opposite of what i wanted. maybe because it is a mutable method, and affects the state directly, but storing it in a variable also did not work.

Comment: splice modifies the array and returns the deleted items. slice returns a new array containing the selected subset. Prior to your edit you were calling slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, that slice returns the elements that you cut out:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
var citrus = fruits.slice(1, 3);
console.log(citrus); // ["Orange", "Lemon"]
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Comment: Using slice did the trick, since it does not affect the array directly. But i dont know why splice() was giving an opposite result of what i expected.

Answer (score 1):

[**slice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) doesn't mutate the array it returns a new array with the selected elements. However, **[splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** mutates the array
so for your example to work using slice you do

```js
data = [1,2,3,4,5]; 
var slicedata=data.slice(2,)
console.log("sliced array", slicedata)
console.log("original array", data)
```

using `splice`

```js
    data = [1,2,3,4,5]; 
    var slicedata=data.splice(2,4)
    console.log("spliced array", slicedata)
    console.log("original array", data) // notice the difference
```